# Trying to pass value of radio button chosen to another function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a screen with a radio button group.  The client does not want them to look like radio buttons, so I have styled the labels and hidden the actual radio buttons.  I have jquery to "highlight" the chosen radio button, and then call a function to process the user's choice:

```
$(function() {
   $('input:radio').change(function(){
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', this.checked).siblings().removeClass('active');
     processStep1(this);
   });  
});
```

This part works fine, it calls the function:

```
function processStep1(v) {
  if ($("input:radio[name='challenge-type']").is(":checked")) {
    $('#step1 .next').removeClass('disabled');
    // which of the challenge-type radios was selected?
    }
 }
```

Which checks to make sure a radio was checked before "enabling" the next button. But at this point, I need to know the VALUE of which radio was chosen, and I'm not sure how to get it without checking the dom a second time; isn't there a way I can get it in the change event in the first function and pass it to the second function?

Comment: Seems like you can use the parameter v of the fucntion processStep1 to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a data attribute for the input (in this case radio button), and when you're calling your function just pass the data attribute's value to the function. You can have the data attribute 
unique to each of the radio buttons, I think that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Fiddle to show one exmaple of a similar code working. This code gets the value of the checkbox and shows in an alert.

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Joqus/cJPzv/

```
 
$(function() {
   $('input:radio').change(function(){
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', this.checked);
       $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

       processStep1(this);
   });
});

function processStep1(v) {
    if(v.checked)
    {
        alert('Value: ' + v.value);
    }
}
```